# Multiple DataGridView on TabPages. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabpage

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    abc()
    Refresh()

    Dim con As String = "Data Source = HCA-ISD03\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = QMS_HCA; User ID=qs; Password=ZAQ!2wsx; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(con)
    Dim Query As String = Nothing
    Dim Query2 As String = Nothing
    Dim Query3 As String = Nothing
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter

    Dim adapter1 As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand


    Query = "Select sMessage, iAlert FROM MAS_Alert"
    Query2 = "SELECT REF_AlertPlate.sPlateNo, MAS_Alert.sMessage, REF_AlertPlate.iAlert, REF_AlertPlate.dStart, REF_AlertPlate.dEnd, REF_AlertPlate.sFrameNo FROM REF_AlertPlate INNER JOIN MAS_Alert ON MAS_Alert.iAlert=REF_AlertPlate.iAlert"
    Query3 = "SELECT iAlert, sMessage, dCreated, iCreatedBy FROM MAS_Alert"


    Try
        conn.Open()

        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, conn)
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(Query2, conn)
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(Query3, conn)

        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()

        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)

        ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing

        ComboBox1.Refresh()
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "iAlert"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "sMessage"

        Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    conn.Close()



End Sub
```

How can I load the datagridView1? The only DataGridView that loads is the DataGridView2. Sorry if I'm wrong, I set the three queries in the formload. What should I do first?? The only query that loads is the **Query** and **Query2**Thank you in advance mates. Hope that you can help me.

Comment: What do you think `adapter.SelectCommand` holds after the four consecutive assignment statements?

Comment: What can I do sir?

Answer (score 0):

I've created another sub for the DataGridView1 then call it in FormLoad

```
Sub Query3()


    Dim con As String = "Data Source = HCA-ISD03\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = QMS_HCA; User ID=qs; Password=ZAQ!2wsx; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(con)
    Dim Query3 As String = Nothing
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter

    Dim adapter1 As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand

    Query3 = "SELECT iAlert, sMessage, dCreated, iCreatedBy FROM MAS_Alert"


    Try
        conn.Open()

        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(Query3, conn)

        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)



    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    conn.Close()




End Sub
```

Problem Solved. Sorry if I made a mistake.